# What is the 'job' of the byproduct water in the Electron Transport Chain?

Tags: cell-biology

I understand what happens in the Electron Transport Cycle, but I fail to understand that after Oxygen has accepted an electron, it forms water, but why? what happens to the water? I can take an educated guess but again its a guess.

Does it then react with ADP?

Thanks in advance! I'm doing an animal welfare course and as part of it I need to study basic biology.

Comment: The formation of water in the matrix at the end of the electron transport chain helps to maintain the hydrogen gradient between the intermembrane space and the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your question.
One reason is, if this chemical reaction does not happen so there will be a lot of electrons in mitochondria in a short time consequently the environment inside the mitochondria will be charged in negative and as we know the environment inside the all parts of cells should not change during the time
and on the other hand, these extra electrons may carry out some chemical reactions which result in producing some materials which are not good for cell, for ex H2O2, as we know it is a poisonous material for cell.
But maybe you ask why H2O and not another product? because H2O exists in cell, in a large amount, it is solvent for many materials, it is not poisonous for cell, and many other reasons.

Comment: _As we know_, _many other reasons_ all these things make you look ignorant to the answer. _Maybe you ask why $\ce{H_2O}$ and not other product_ No, as much as I can see, the OP is not asking this in any way.